# Cannot set the ShowsNavigationUI property of a wpf page using style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this code block?

```
   <Style x:Key="PageStyle" TargetType="Page">
        <Setter Property="ShowsNavigationUI" Value="False" />
   </Style>
```

the Error list in VS says: 
Exception has been thrown by a target of an invocation.

Thanks

Comment: See the `inner exception`, it must be crashing somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the NavigatioUIVisibilty of the Frame Control to "Hidden"